# SQL Server 2012 creating string of values from a table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return column values from a table into a string with is a variable.

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @START_T_DATE VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @END_T_DATE VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @START_T_DATE = '1 Feb 2017'                       
SET @END_T_DATE = '1 Apr 2017'

SET @SCRIPT = "SET NOCOUNT ON
   SELECT   
   '['+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yyyy, DATE))+'_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(mm, DATE))+'],' AS YEAR_MONTH
INTO ##YEAR_MONTH
FROM " + @database +"statement_runs (NOLOCK)
WHERE stmt_date >= '"+ @START_T_DATE+"'
AND stmt_date < '"+ @END_T_DATE+"'
GROUP BY '['+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yyyy, DATE))+'_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(mm, DATE))+'],'"
```

Which returns the following

```
YEAR_MONTH
----------
[2017_2],
[2017_3],
```

I then want to loop thru the results in this table and return into variable `@col` the following string, removing the comma from the last value.

```
@col = ('[2017_2],[2017_3]')
```

So what I've tried is looping, by checking if there is a value in the `##YEAR_MONTH` table, but the loop is not stopping...

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM ##YEAR_MONTH)
BEGIN
    SET @COL = '(' SELECT YEAR_MONTH
                   FROM ##YEAR_MONTH
END


YEAR_MONTH
----------
[2017_2],
[2017_3],
```

I've also tried this, but only returns one value

```
SET @COL = '('''+YEAR_MONTH+''')'
FROM ##YEAR_MONTH

('[2017_3],')
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT @COL +=...` instead of `SET @COL =` and `STUFF(@COL, LEN(@COL) - 1, 1, '')`. If the comma is at the start instead of at the end, removing the leading comma becomes as easy as `STUFF(@COL, 1, 1, '')`. That said, your whole query can probably be simplified apart from this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing me in the right direction...I've tried the following and it seems to do what I want.  SET @COL = SELECT '('''+STUFF((SELECT ',' + [year_month]
     FROM ##YEAR_MONTH
     ORDER BY [year_month]
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')+''')' AS [Output]

Answer (score 0):

Using a calendar table to simulate your source query, and using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170201'; 
declare @thrudate date = '20170331';
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select 
  year_months = stuff((
      select distinct ', '+convert(varchar(7),[Date],120)
      from dates
      order by 1
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WGWUK54259

returns:

```
+------------------+
|   year_months    |
+------------------+
| 2017-02, 2017-03 |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ad-hoc tally table if you don't have a tally/calendar table.

This should produce what I presume is your desired formatted string, for what I also presume is for a dynamic pivot.

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2017-02-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-04-01'

Declare @col varchar(max)
Select @col = Stuff((Select ',' +QuoteName(Format(D,'yyyy_M')) 
                    From (
                            Select Top (DateDiff(MONTH,@Date1,@Date2)) 
                                   D=DateAdd(MONTH,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),@Date1) 
                             From  master..spt_values
                             Order By 1
                         ) X 
                    For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 

Select @col
```

Returns

```
[2017_2],[2017_3]
```